# 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix' as input for models

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, sparse-matrix

I am using `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` for handling categorical values in my model. I noticed the results of the 'transform' method is a sparse matrix `scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix` and it seems that it can be used directly for training the model (in this case, Ridge regression).

When dealing with toy problems (<100 examples), it seems that there is no difference if I feed the model with the sparse matrix or with the corresponding np array of the matrix (`matrix.toarray()`), but with larger datasets (>20K examples) it looks to me that the conversion to array is absolutely required.

I know there are some issues when using sparse matrices (for example the dot product of np throws errors) and I am wondering if this is another, and therefore I should always use np arrays as input for the scikit-learn models.

Comment: Models which accept sparse matrices should give the same results as with the equivalent dense matrix. Can you show a specific, reproducible example where the results differ?

Comment: The screen shot is not all that helpful. Can you include a minimal code example that other people can run which reproduces the error?

Comment: I will check my code line by line to see if there is any bug. Otherwise I will do my best to create an example that reproduces the error. However, thanks for the reply.